# onCreateView() is never called in Fragment

Tags: java, android

i want to build the next UI:
TabLayout with 2 tabs and 2 different Fragments (Solved and Unsolved)
My onCreateView in Fragment is never called.

Here I inflate my viewPager:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new UnsolvedTasksFragment());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new SolvedTasksFragment());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(getString(R.string.tablayout_unsolved));
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.tablayout_solved));

}
```

My custom ViewPagerAdapter:

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (!mFragmentList.isEmpty() && mFragmentList.size() > id)
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    return new Fragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Here an example of my Fragment:

```
 public class SolvedTasksFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewClickListenerSolved {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //Some code here;
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClick(View v, int position) {
       }
}
```

Maybe somebody can tell what is wrong.
I don't need  the whole solution.

Comment: Can you show your `getItem(int)` and `getCount()` implementations? It's going to be easier for us to assess your problem.

Comment: what is `id` here now ?

Comment: id is an id of ui elements import static android.R.attr.id;

Comment: interesting, I am curious why you need to use android.R.attr.id before returning necessary fragment? did you check if `return mFragmentList.get(position);` is called at the first place?

Comment: @hakim hmmm... when I reduced this statement (> id) it actually works.
It seems like I needed this checking but it s not actually needed now. Thx!

Comment: awesome :) . just minor suggestion, I think it is better in your `ViewPagerAdapter `#getPageTitle(int position)  returning title directly. for example by using `switch(position){ .... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the adapter and then add the fragments. Do it like this.
Change these statements

```
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new UnsolvedTasksFragment());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new SolvedTasksFragment());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

to these

```
mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.addFragment(new UnsolvedTasksFragment());
mAdapter.addFragment(new SolvedTasksFragment());
```

Comment: Those are both `abstract`. They would've had to have overridden them, or else their code wouldn't compile. They've apparently just omitted them in the question.

Comment: I just reduced these methods for compact view. I overrided in real

Comment: I tried it produces an exception ( PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 2 Pager id: com.divofmod.quizerfield:id/viewpager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.divofmod.quizerfield.Adapters.ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: @ManOfWar Please accept it as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

[`From docs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#id)

The value of `id` is `16842960` so

```
if (true && 2 > 16842960) // will not be executed 
   // true && false => false
```

Solution : you can check the size against `position` or remove this check if not specific to the implementation

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (mFragmentList.size() > position)
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    return new Fragment();
}
```